# edit a remote file with vim

Tags: linux, vim, scp

I'm trying to edit a remote file with vim 7.2 using this command
":e scp://username@host//home/oracle/filename.ksh". But I get this error "scp: not found". Then I placed the scp file in home/oracle. But still I get the same error. What am I missing?

Comment: You cant do it that way - why are you trying to edit the scp command?

Comment: @AdrianCornish he's trying to use KDE protocols (not sure if other DMs allow it too.)

Comment: @kaoD what are you taling about? scp = Secure Copy it has nothing to do with a windows mananger - OMG - do you even know what you are talking about

Comment: which version of vim? http://superuser.com/questions/148865/how-can-i-check-which-version-of-vim-i-have-installed

Comment: @AdrianCornish vim past 6.0 has the ability to use scp refs with :e. See e.g. [this vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim)

Comment: @chemicalkt scp in your $path? use :echo $path in vim to check. also pasting the output of :vim version or vim --version might help

Comment: @pb2q Thanks for correcting me - never knew that was possible and I just tried it and it work. Get set in your ways when you spend too long doing something. Thanks for teaching me something new :-) - but I do say it has nothing to do with KDE ;-)

Comment: @pb2q I tried as mentioned in ur link but I get the same error. My problem is same as mentioned in http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/ssh/message/13676

Comment: @AdrianCornish because KIO is part of the KDE architecture and chemicalkt's use is pretty close to what KIO offers. I don't even use KDE, so I don't see why do you need to personally attack me. Just acknowledge your mistake... By the way, DM and WM are completely different things (although pretty tied in many cases.)

Comment: chemicalkt reviewing your question I see that you may misunderstand a few things. moving scp on the remote machine will do nothing. scp must be available as a command in the same place that you run vim as a command. if you're running from a terminal, try typing something like _whereis scp_. though if you can run scp, you're probably better off following ziesemer advice below

Comment: @kaoD I am always up for discussion - but I do not see anything to do with the acronyms you mention in OP's original question "edit a remote file with vim". So to confirm your point in a way I do not know what KIO is and I havent looked - because the question never mentioned it. Nor did his question mention solar flares affect on editing files - but I am not BOF

Comment: @AdrianCornish so you don't know what KIO is but still go all arrogant and harsh over me. That's not a good attitude. KIO API looks exactly like chemicalkt's example so I'm pretty sure he just expected KIO to work system-wide, while it's only KDE wide. You couldn't see it because you don't know KIO, but I do. Then why go all arrogant over me instead of researching?

Comment: @kaoD I spent many years dealing with knock downs on usenet - grow a pair and deal with it. I do not need to research the crap you answer with when you are trying to answer the question you make it rather than reading the question the OP asked.

Comment: @AdrianCornish you're obviously too arrogant to acknowledge your error. I refuse to continue this conversation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since Vim 6.x the **netrw plugin** is installed as a standard plugin. So you can edit files via ftp, rcp, scp or http.

For `scp` actions is useful to open the file as follows:

```
vim scp://remoteuser@server.tld//path/to/document
```

You get a bunch of information on [Vim tips pages](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim).

Comment: Another option, from `:help netrw`:  `:Nread "scp://[user@]machine[[:#]port]/path`, or `:Nread "scp://username@host/home/oracle/filename.ksh"` according to the data provided.

Comment: this is good info, but it doesn't really address the question. chemicalkt is already trying to use netrw/:e scp and having problems with it

Comment: @pb2q At the end @chemicalkt problems are related to the shell, since it is not allowed to do `scp`, `vim` on the server neither.

Answer (score 4):

Depending of your OS software configuration, you can alternately use fuse and sshfs in order to accomplish this.

---

Packaged as sshfs in most distributions, this makes possible for users (depending on your user permissions policy) to actually mount a ssh location somewhere in the local filesystem.

The command looks something like this (assuming you already installed sshfs):

```
sshfs <user>@<host>:<remote_location> <local_path>
```

An example:

```
sshfs root@test.example.org:/var/www /mnt/sshfsmounts/www
```

Doing that, you can safely edit remote files as if they made part of your local filesystem, using

```
vim /mnt/sshfsmounts/www/index.php
```

for example.

---

Some useful links here:

[1] - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS

[2] - http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

[3] - http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8904

---

Be aware of the fact that permissions you will have on mounted ssh filesystem are those applied for the user specified inthe `sshfs` command, completed by permissions you have on the local file system for the mount point. This means you basically *need* to have write access on both the mount point and on the ssh host under specified sshfs user.

Answer (score 3):

You should ssh to `host`, then use a copy of vim there to edit the file:

```
ssh username@host
vim /home/oracle/filename.ksh
```

Otherwise, if you must, scp the file locally (outside of vim), edit it, then scp the file back to `host`:

```
scp username@host:/home/oracle/filename.ksh .
vim filename.ksh
scp filename.ksh username@host:/home/oracle/
```

Comment: Seems like I'm not getting the basic stuffs...Where should I hit these commands?

Comment: @chemicalkt - From your shell (e.g. bash), before launching vim.

Comment: I'm on Windows and I used a secure shell client(software) to connect to linux server. In the bash shell provided by secure shell client, I tried to vim but it says "vim: command not found".